# User is already logged in and save data into core data using api

Tags: swift, api, authentication

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    let loginRequest = [
        "phone_no" : self.numberTxt.text! as String,
        "password" : self.passwordTxt.text! as String
    ]
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Mashape-Key": "user_id",
        "x-access-token": "user_token"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https:/user/login", method: .post, parameters: loginRequest, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { 
            (response) in switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                self.loggedInUserData  = response.value as? NSDictionary
                //print(self.loggedInUserData)
                let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
                // print ("return as JSON using swiftyJson is: \(swiftyJson)")
                let name = swiftyJson["name"].stringValue
                let phone = swiftyJson["phoneNo"].stringValue
                print(name)
                print(phone)
                print("Khabbab ")
            }
        }
```

I want to log in and store data so then it doesn't need to log in again
this code is log in and gives me some value also

Comment: Optional({
    data =     {
        "checkin_channel" = "customer_checkin_5bf3ab3d0a4ef";
        email = "<null>";
        fcmToken = "";
        id = 128;
        "is_new" = 0;
        name = kha;
        "notification_channel" = "customer_notification_5bf3ab3d26080";
        phoneNo = 123456789;
        token = "$2y$10$01UpwCUVXnTQevsKtdpg9eRajVRfRzVU/qbUCKTtU/FV7gKKM4cOO";
    };
    mgs = "Login Successful";
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UserDefaults` for this.

When user is successfully logged

```
if swiftyJson["msg"].stringValue == "Login Successful"
```

set `true` for key `"isUserLogged"`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLogged")
```

then you can get this value for the same key and if user isn't logged (value is `false`) or if you haven't set value for this key yet (value is `nil`), you can perform login

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isUserLogged") == nil || !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLogged") {
    // perform login
}
```

so your `login` action should look like this

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isUserLogged") == nil || !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLogged") {
        ...
        Alamofire.request("https:/user/login", method: .post, parameters: loginRequest, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                ...
                if swiftyJson["msg"].stringValue == "Login Successful" {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLogged")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help   plece tell me why it desn't store value from json data?   let name = swiftyJson["name"].stringValue
                let phone = swiftyJson["phoneNo"].stringValue

Comment: Because they are properties of `data` object. Use `swiftyJson["data"]["name"].stringValue`